# jQuery animation tab slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in js and jQuery. I wrote animation tab-slider. But my code is bad. What should I improve? What should I do to make the code less cumbersome?

```js
var slideTabImg = $('.js-slide-tabImg');
var firstTab = $('#js-first-tabImg');
var secondTab = $('#js-second-tabImg');

$('#js-first-tab').click(function(){
    $(this).next().removeClass('m-slideTa href');
    $(this).addClass('m-slideTab-href');

    slideTabImg.removeClass('m-slide-tabImg_active');
    slideTabImg.removeClass('m-secondTab-active m-firstTab-active');

    secondTab.addClass('m-secondTab-active');
    firstTab.addClass('m-slide-tabImg_active m-firstTab-active');
});

$('#js-second-tab').click(function(){
  $(this).prev().removeClass('m-slideTab-href');
  $(this).addClass('m-slideTab-href');

   slideTabImg.removeClass('m-secondTab-active m-firstTab-active');
  slideTabImg.removeClass('m-slide-tabImg_active');
  
  secondTab.addClass('m-slide-tabImg_active m-firstTab-active');
  firstTab.addClass('m-secondTab-active');
});
```

```css
.slide-tabImages {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 860px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide-tabImg {
 position: absolute;
}
.m-slide-tabImg_active {
 top: 40px;
 left: -40px;
 z-index: 5
}
.slide-tab {
 padding: 30px 0;
}
.slideTab-href {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: normal;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 8px;
}
.slideTab-href:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.slideTabLink {
 padding-top: 80px;
}
.m-slideTab-href {
 border-bottom: 1px dashed;
 }

.m-secondTab-active {
  animation: secondTab-animation 2.5s forwards;
}

.m-firstTab-active {
  animation: firstTab-animation 2.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes secondTab-animation {
  49% {
    transform: translateX(-120px);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes firstTab-animation {
  49% {
    transform: translateX(120px);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=" slideTabLink">
 <a id="js-first-tab" class=" slideTab-href m-slideTab-href">New</a>
 <a id="js-second-tab" class=" slideTab-href">Old</a>
</div>
   
<div class=" slide-tab js-slide-tab">
 <div class=" slide-tabImages">
 <div class=" slide-tabImg m-slide-tabImg_active js-slide-tabImg" id="js-first-tabImg">
   <img src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/5a/fe/b6/5afeb68da321d060058111.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class=" slide-tabImg js-slide-tabImg" id="js-second-tabImg">
   <img src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/5a/fe/b6/5afeb6aea3f83085649799.png" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```